# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error in android

Tags: android

I try to import a .jar lib.
Add in code, I import it with no error.

```
import my.lib.MyLib;
```

And I use the class MyLib which in the lib in onCreate().
But it show below error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: my.lib.MyLib
```

What is the possible reason? 
And how to modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you has update to ADT r17.
You can see [this](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17).